# Getline() keeps skipping lines in for loop

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to print the value of variables, one of them is pointer and the second one is simply an int.

I did assign a value to a pointer - a, and than I assigned pointer to variable. I'm trying to output the value of variable which meant to show the value of pointer, but I got nowhere.

Since the compiler shows the following warning:

'a' is used unitialized in this function

and eventually after compilation proccess is done I get the error while running program, windows pop-up tells me that:

"The instruction at 0x00401359 referenced memory at 0x00417c7e. The memory could not be written. Click on OK to terminate the program."

What is wrong with this piece of code ?

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

int main(void) 
{
   int *a; 
   int b; 
   *a = 5;
   b = *a; 

   cout << b << " " << *a; 

}
```

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: What do you think of your compiler's warning: *'a' is used unitialized in this function* ?

Comment: You need to allocate memory for the pointer first.

Comment: ...where is the call to `getline` exactly?

Answer (score 2):

`a` is a pointer and it should point somewhere. If you do not initialize it, it points just anywhere, thus your assignment `*a=5` tries to write into a random memory address.

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

int main(void) 
{
   int c;       // reserves some space for a to point to
   int *a = &c; // NOW a is initialized and it points to c 
   int b; 
   *a = 5;      // writes 5 into the variable c
   b = *a; 

   cout << b << " " << *a; 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
   int *a;
   int b;
   a=&b;
   *a = 5;

   cout << b << " " << *a;

}
```

Your pointer a does not have a variable address on which it can save this value.